# Pregenerating Bluetooth link keys

Tags: bluetooth

In my project, there will be about `500` Bluetooth devices installed over the city and about `20` PDAs used to update these devices.

The devices should be not be visible to anything except the `PDAs` and I'd like to avoid the troubles or pairing each device to each PDA.

Is there any way to pregenerate `10,000` link keys (for each device-PDA pair), knowing their device addresses, so that link keys for each of the devices could be uploaded all at once during the firmware upload process?

Comment: I think that you need to add more specific informations about the PDAs and devices (i.e. vendor, OS used, ...)

Answer (score 3):

define a shared secret and use the mac-addresses as salt.
with this, you are able to generate a key, which is known on both systems.

or something like that :)

pseudo:

```
key = int(private part (shared secret) + public part (mac-address))
```